# update value while ruuning long process in C# .net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a long process loop and while its running I want to show the updated value in textbox or label using ajax or jquery, I have tried to add event timer and put the value n Session while its is running the loop, but it doesn't work it show the time but not the new value of session

in aspx file

```
 <div>
           <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
                  <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" 
        Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick"></asp:Timer>
        </div>

        <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl" 
        runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName ="tick" />
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

in aspx.cs file

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

     if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2000);
            }
    }



 protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       TimeSpan time1 = new TimeSpan();
            time1 = (DateTime)Session["timeout"] - DateTime.Now;
            if (time1.Seconds <= 0)
            {
                lblTimer.Text = "TimeOut!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblTimer.Text = Session["test"].ToString() + " " + time1.Seconds.ToString();
            }
}
```

this value Session["test"].ToString() is updated to a new value on every iteration of long process loop. Any help!!!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_multi_threading.htm

Comment: I've posted a similar answer to a similar problem here: [Display output from command line program realtime in asp.net][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22951771/381419